# Merge data frames and divide rows by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, division

I would like to divide the values from `df1` over the values from `df2`. In this reproducible example, I am able to sum these values. What about the division? Thanks in advance!

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("a", "b", "c"), year1 = c(1, 2, 3), year2 = c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(country = c("a", "b", "d"), year1 = c(1, 2, NA), year2 = c(1, 2, 3))

df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, tidyr::replace_na, 0) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise_all(., sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  na_if(., 0)
```

Expected result is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  country year1 year2
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a           1     1
2 b           1     1
3 c          NA    NA
4 d          NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are groups with 2 rows and some with 1, use an `if/else` condition within `summarise/across` to divide the `first` element by the `last` `if` there are two elements or `else` return NA

```
library(dplyr) # version 1.0.4
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na, 0)) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(n() == 2) first(.)/last(.) 
          else NA_real_))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  country year1 year2
#* <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a           1     1
#2 b           1     1
#3 c          NA    NA
#4 d          NA    NA
```

Comment: I was really looking forward to `first(.)/last(.)`. Is there any documentation on this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @bttomio It is just that there are only two rows.  So, we extract the first element and last or you can do `.[1]/.[2]` Or may use`reduce(`/`)` as well if it is a list

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `merge` + `split.default`

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "country", all = TRUE)
cbind(
  df[1],
  list2DF(lapply(
    split.default(df[-1], gsub("\\.(x|y)", "", names(df)[-1])),
    function(v) do.call("/", v)
  ))
)
```

which gives

```
  country year1 year2
1       a     1     1
2       b     1     1
3       c    NA    NA
4       d    NA    NA
```